# MACRO for checking an array is empty in c

Tags: c, macros

I need to check if an array is empty using macros. If the size of array is constant say 2, then I will be able to write a macro like

```
#define IS_EMPTY(arr)  \
  ((arr[0] | arr[1]) == 0)
```

But if arr is defined like this

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 100
int arr[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

Is there any way, a macro can determine that the array is empty? Or is inline functions the only option.

Comment: Why do you _need_ to use macros?

Comment: What does "empty" mean? There's no "empty" in C.

Comment: @emartel Just curious. I saw some code that does it when array size is 2, like in the first example. So I was wondering if it is possible to modify it to a more generic macro

Comment: What if your array `int arr[array_size]` is comprised of just 0. But as it happens those are measured values? Is the array still 'empty'?

Comment: I see that preprocessor macros are `ALL_CAPS_BY_DEFAULT`, but please avoid this convention in post titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your most viable options would be a loop:

```
int IsEmpty(char * array, size) {
 int i;
 for (i=0; i<size; i++)
   if (array[i] != 0)
      return 0;
 return 1;
}
```

or memcmp:

```
int IsEmpty(char * array, size) {
 char * emptyArray = malloc(size);
 memset(emptyArray, 0, size);
 int res = memcmp(array, emptyArray, size);
 free(emptyArray);
return res==0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the definition of the array is seen. i.e. struct foo arr[]={initialization_list}, then 
array_length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(element_of_array);

Other ways around it could be pointer arithmetic with *assumption* that global variables are allocated without (much) padding.

extern int a[]={2,4,5};
extern int b=1;

size = (&b-&a[0])/sizeof(int);